# How to use Class type Generic in a method

Tags: java, generics

I have a method that implements an interface method.  it looks like this:

```
@Override
public Double calculate(Class<Float> score) {

    if (score == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Double beta0 = new Double(-7.7631);
    Double beta1 = new Double(0.0737);
    Double beta2 = new Double(0.9971);

    Log log = new Log();
    Exp exp = new Exp();

    Double logit = beta0 + (beta1 * score) + (beta2 * log.value(new Double(score + 1)));
    Double rod = exp.value(logit) / (1 + exp.value(logit));

    return rod;
}
```

The interface

```
public interface Calculator<T,S> {
    public T calculate(Class<S> params);
}
```

I get a compile error that `the operator '*' is not defined for the argument type(s) Double, Class<Float>`.

I guess I expected this, but don't really know how to fix it.  Apologies if this is a simple question.....

Comment: You should probably do some reading on `Class<?>`

Comment: It’s also unclear why you are using classes at all. Your code has no advantage of using `Double` instead of `double` and using `new Double(…)` takes it to the max.

Comment: I was trying to use generics so that some implementations of the calculator could take other types

Comment: Generics require the parameter and return type to be boxed types, but there is no reason for any of the local variables to be a boxed type. The result will automatically boxed when you `return` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want a `Class<Float>` but just a `Float` as your method parameter.

Mathematical operators don't apply to the `Class` type, which is used to define an actual class (e.g. used in reflection).

Also, careful with operations on `double`s, `float`s and their wrappers: the precision can be lost an yield unexpected results.

I advise to use `BigDecimal` at least internally.

**Note**

It seems you are `@Override`ing your method, which likely implies a bigger issue with class design. 
I would advise to check on the parent class and infer why the `calculate` method takes a `Class` as parameter.

**Edit**

I would change your interface method to:

```
public T calculate(S param);
```

You could also consider binding your generic types upwards to extend `Number`.

Something in the lines of:

```
public interface Calculator<T extends Number, S extends Number> {
    public T calculate(S param);
}
```

... and an anonymous example for implementation:

```
Calculator<Double, Float> calc = new Calculator<Double, Float>() {
    public Double calculate(Float param) {
        // TODO logic 
        return null;
    };
};
```

Comment: ok - I have included the Interface.  I have a bunch of different calculators that take different arguments, but have the same basic structure.  Is there a "better" way to structure this?

Comment: This is really helpful.  The thinking behind this originally was that I also wanted to pass more complex parameter lists (for example ArrayLists or beans) to some calculators.  I really like the concept of extending Number, maybe your first suggestion of (S param) is more suitable for my application

Comment: @skyman glad it helped. If you want to pass multiple arguments you could also use a varargs: simply change the signature in interface to `public T calculate(S... params)` and adapt the implementation.

Comment: This is a useful idea as well!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use

```
Double logit = beta0 + (**beta1 * score**) + (beta2 * log.value(new Double(score + 1)));
```

because operatator "*" is not defined for it... You can not multiply these two different types. You can use float instead.

Comment: That is what the question is

Comment: I get a similar error if I change the generic type to Double?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the `double` value from `Double` class. Like:

```
Double beta0 = new Double(0.07);
double x = beta0.doubleValue();
```

Or use the `double` primitive data type in all your code.

Cheers!

Comment: That was true more than ten years ago…